# ruby multiple assignment not working as expected

Tags: ruby

I am trying to do something like this:

```
a = b = c = []

a << 1
```

Now I am expecting that `b` and `c` will be an `empty array`, whereas `a` will have one element. But its not working like that, here `b` and `c` also contains the same element, how is it working like this?

Comment: That is because `a`, `b`, and `c` all *refer* to the same array.

Comment: This is not what the term multiple assignment usually refers to. Multiple assignment is of the form `a, b = c, d`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you do this

```
a = b = c = []
```

All three variables point to the same location in memory. They are three references to same location in memory

So when you do

`a << 1`, you are writing to the memory space referred by all three variables

Comment: OP can do `a.object_id`, `b.object_id`, ... to see this more clearly.

Comment: @Akavall but when we are assigning `a = b = 0`,  and checking the `a.object_id` and `b.object_id` then also they are coming same but their is totally different from  `a = b = []`

Answer (score 2):

If you want 3 separate arrays, do:

```
a, b, c = [], [], []
```

Comment: This is likely what the OP meant to do. Though, technically it doesn't answer his question.

Comment: Okay I see what you mean, you are right. @Vimsha has already explained it so didn't want to duplicate the answer, just gave a solution

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.dup` to create an object with same value at different memory location.

Here is your example without `c` because it is irrelevant.

```
irb(main):028:0> a = b = []
=> []
irb(main):029:0> a.object_id #a and b refer to the same location in memory
=> 19502520
irb(main):030:0> b.object_id
=> 19502520
irb(main):031:0> b = a.dup
=> []
irb(main):032:0> b.object_id #b refers to different location in memory
=> 18646920
irb(main):033:0> a << 1
=> [1]
irb(main):034:0> b
=> []
```